# How do I select data from the excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[image: Pivot Sheet]
**Pivot Sheet**

So for example when I click the cell `G14` in the pivot sheet. It should display `9 data` in another sheet say Sheet1. The number of data depends on the cells in `column G` of pivot sheet. I cant seem to find any code to get that data.

[image: Sheet1]
**Sheet1**

I need to to know how I can access that data using VBA.

Comment: What is "9 data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SelectAndCopyPaste()
Dim lastrow() As String
Dim pt As PivotTable


Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

With Worksheets("Pivot Sheet")
    .Activate
    Set pt = .PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    lastrow = Split(pt.RowRange.Address, ":")
    .Range(lastrow(1)).Offset(-1, 6).Select 'here is where you set which cell you want to choose
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Selection.Copy
End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: You should avoid using [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your Code.

Comment: @Mikku do you have any other suggestions or way to make this better?

Comment: Just avoid using Select & Activate. As you are already referring to the correct objects.